# Delete discontinue products in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

In my Magento site I want to remove(delete) discontinue(No longer) products.
But I don't know how to find which product is discontinued product and how to remove(delete) them.

Please anybody have script.

Comment: wt do you mean by discountinue product qty =0, or status=disable ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a delete_products.php file in magento's root folder.

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('log_errors', TRUE);

//Include the Mage package
require_once './app/Mage.php';

//Set Developer mode to true, allows for more verbose errors
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

//Initialize the app.
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku','status'))->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);

foreach ($products as $product) {
    try {
        echo "<pre>Deleting ".$product->getSku().", status: ".$product->getStatus()."</pre>";
        $product->delete();
        echo '<pre>OK</pre>';

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "<pre>ERROR: ".$e->getMessage()."</pre>";
    }
}
```

Run [MAGENTO SITE URL]/delete_products.php

It is not as fast as direct SQL delete but it works.

[Reindex](https://www.branded3.com/blog/re-indexing-magento-command-line/) after script is done.